# Maximum product of Bitwise AND and Bitwise OR

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

We are provided an array. 
We need to find out 2 indices **i and j (i!=j)** such that
the given value
**X(i,j)= (Arr[i]&Arr[j]) * (Arr[i]|Arr[j])**
is maximal, where & stands for Bitwise AND and | stands for Bitwise OR.

We need to print this max value of X.

```
1<=Size of array<=100000  
1<=Arr[i]<=1000000000
```

Example-

```
N=4  
Arr[]= 2 3 4 5  
Ans is 20 ( (4&5) * (4|5) )
```

I found out that maximum AND can be found easily by solution of O(N*32), but for bitwise OR and maintaining both simultaneously, it is getting difficult.

Comment: What are the actual values of the array? Is *kernelization* possible? E.g. when you have `7 == 111b` you can eliminate `1..6` since `7 & x > (1..6) & x` and  `7 & x >= (1..6) | x`

Comment: Values can range from 1 to 10^9

Comment: Is it a normal multiplication modulo a power of two, or a full bigint product?

Comment: as max array elem is 1e9 , the product of 2 elem won't go above 1e18. There is no modulo operation involved.